# Java primitive type storage

Tags: java, types, primitive

I know primitives variables store values and obj variables store references. But technically is a primitive variable a reference to the location where the primitive value is in memory? B/c you have to know the location of the value.

Comment: Yes ... and no.  Yes(-ish) - because when a primitive is stored in variable in memory, the memory cell has a address.  No for a number of reasons.  1) Variables are not always stored in memory. 2) The address of a variable is not constant; e.g. when the GC moves an object ... 3)  The (instantaneous) address of a variable is not a *reference* in the sense that Java uses that term.

Comment: *B/c you have to know the location of the value.* - Actually, the location is "known" relative to something else; i.e. an object, a stack frame, or a class frame ... depending on what kind of variable you are talking about.

Comment: 'Reference' is a technical word **defined by the programming language**, so in Java: no.   In some other programming languages: yes.